# Highstock disable Tooltip but show Flag

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

I have a chart in highstocks. In my chart I want to show flags on the point. But i want to disable the point tooltip and show only flags.
When i add the following code, flags tooltip is also disabled.

```
tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
```

The chart link is [flags chart](http://jsfiddle.net/ep7jxtx3/)

Please suggest, the changes I need to do.

Comment: When you disable tooltip like you quote, what is wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ep7jxtx3/1/ seems to working as you need.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : But i want tooltip on the flag. It should be visible on the flag, not on the point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the formatter and then set condition which checks series type.

```
tooltip:{
            formatter:function() {
                var point = Highcharts.splat(this.point);

                if(point[0] && point[0].series.options.type == 'flags') {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %B %d, %Y',point[0].x );
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ep7jxtx3/2/